# How do we prove the statement $x^{2} \geq 36$ implies $|x| \geq 6$ by contradiction?

Tags: proof-explanation

Proof by contradiction seems to confuse me and I need help with this specific question.

In particular, how do we prove the following statement by contradiction:

If $x^2 \geq 36$ then $|x|\geq 6$ (?)

Comment: Thank you @Átila Correia. I'm still new to this

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Also welcome from me! A very important tip here is that when asking a question, you should explain what you have tried and what didn't work out, so we can help you better. Just posting the problem might attract downvotes.

Comment: Got it @SamuelAdrianAntz Understood!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy :). Assume $|x|<6$, and just square the result. Around $x=6$, $x^2$ increases as $x$ increases. If $x<6$, $x^2<6^2=36$. Since $x^2$ is an even function, $(-x)^2<36$ as well, and that's our contradiction.

Comment: Ohh okayyy Thank you so much!